# How do I check if a facebook page exists?

Tags: php, facebook

How do I check if a facebook page, group, or person exists using php?

Robert

Comment: Maybe rather ask "how do I check...?" in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with Facebook API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

```
$facebook->api('PAGEID or USERID here');
```

If not exists, facebook return `false`.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for a list of sample URLs

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, that worked, but when the page, person, or group doesn't exist I get this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: hreherehere thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1106". How can I suppress that so my own error is shown when $facebook->api('PAGEID or USERID'); returns false?

Comment: @RobertH I don't know exactly, you need to read documentation.

Comment: Try-Catch worked, thank you. Do you guys know how I can limit it and check if the page entered is a group or page and not a personal page. Because I'm using the result to output a like box and if its a personal page it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I answered it using your input. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks Gabriel Santos, Is there a way to find the result using Facebook Token / Access Token?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, if you access a not existing facebook page, you get this message:

> **The page you requested was not found.**
>   You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

So basically you can do a:

```
$page = file_get_contents( 'http://www.facebook.com/no_real_page' );
$pos = strrpos( $page, 'The page you requested was not found' );
if ( $pos === true ) {
  // non existing page!
}
```

But be vary, the message might change and then you will get no result on that script. So better put it in a constant somewhere that you can easily change later:

```
# config.php
define ( FACEBOOK_ERROR, 'The page you requested was not found' );

# script.php
$page = file_get_contents( 'http://www.facebook.com/no_real_page' );
$pos = strrpos( $page, FACEBOOK_ERROR );
if ( $pos === true ) {
  // non existing page!
}
```

Comment: You can always create an array and check every value with foreach.

Comment: Shouldn't you check for HTTP code 404 instead? It's more reliable

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez This post is almost 3 years old. I have no idea what type of response FB sends you now, but at that time there was no 404 message code.

Comment: Still no 404 code... I only get one at *rare* occasions

Answer (score 1):

Facebook not supports `file_get_contents` Or `cUrl` as `Dainis Abols` said.

The code is useful for other websites to check anything existed or not.  But Facebook is quite differ from other websites.

> ```
> <?php
> $page = file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/pages/Studentmug/349363763205');
> $pos = strrpos( $page, 'The page you requested was not found' );
> echo "$page";
> if ( $pos === true ) {
>   // non existing page!
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Radhakrishna Chowdary! Nice to see you helping peoples from your first time =)

Comment: Indeed, if you try to cURL the web page, you may get a 302 redirect to https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser. Though, you still can bypass this Facebook filter by setting the cURL request with an accepted `User-Agent` header.

Answer (score -1):

You would need the facebook_id or url of the user/group.
Then using curl, you could look for the status code returned.
404 means, it does not exist.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I tried that but facebook has a page that shows "
The page you requested was not found.." and that doesn't give a 404 code.

Answer (score -2):

Ok thanks to Gabriel Santos and Jeff, this is what I ended up with:

```
// A function to check if a facebook page exists 
// and if its a personal or published page  
function CheckFB($fbexist) { // $fbexist is the pageID or userID
    require_once("include/facebook.php"); // Facebook php-sdk

                // Install and Initialize
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'APP_ID/KEY';
    $config['secret'] = 'APP_SECRET';

          // Create Facebook object
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    try {
        $facebook->api($fbexist);
        if (!$facebook->api($fbexist)) {  // if this returns false
            $personal = "No";       // it's not a personal page
        } else {                          // or group
            $personal = "Yes";
        }

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {           // If there is an exception
        $checked = array(false, $personal);// the page doesn't exist
        return $checked;
    }
          $checked = array(true, $personal);
    return $checked;
}
```

Thanks again for your help guys :)

Comment: Why you unaccept my answer? My answer say exactly what you want to solve your problem. -1 for this attitude.

Comment: well I didn't use your answer exactly, I used part of it. So no need to give me -1 I accepted your answer now